# Fourier Series of this function

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Find the Fourier series of this function, **only by using sine functions.** 
This is not a homework, I'm just practicing different problems for an exam. 
I know that all coefficients, except b0 should be 0. 
I'm just not sure how to integrate this, because this intervals are confusing me. 
Also, I can't find any similar problem on the internet, and there is no similar example solved in the book. Any help would be appreciated.

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x,  & x∈[0,\pi] \\[2ex]
-x, & x∈[\pi,2\pi]
\end{cases}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the sine series (if I understand you correctly), you first extend your function to an odd function:
$$
\tilde f(x)=
\begin{cases}
-x & -2\pi<x<-\pi\\
x & -\pi\leq x\leq \pi\\
-x & \pi<x\leq 2\pi
\end{cases}
$$
Then calculate the Fourier coefficients of this $4\pi$-periodic function as usual:
$$
a_n=\frac{2}{4\pi}\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi}\tilde f(x)\cos\frac{2\pi n x}{4\pi}\,dx=0
$$
since the integrand is odd, and (here we use in the second step that the integrand is even)
$$
\begin{aligned}
b_n&=\frac{2}{4\pi}\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi}\tilde f(x)\sin\frac{2\pi n x}{4\pi}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)\sin\frac{n x}{2}\,dx=\cdots
\end{aligned}
$$
insert the definition of $f$ and calculate the integral.